Woman leaves temple to learn how to fight
I need help figuring out the name of the movie and the actress in this picture. I know its not a great picture but if anyone can help i'll be very thankful

Details that I can remember:

It takes place at a temple run by women
One of the sisters has left the temple to learn about love so she can learn some fighting moves.   
She gets her heartbroken and goes crazy and comes back to the temple to kill all the sisters.  
She gives one of the other sisters time so she can learn fighting moves. This involves falling in love and experiencing life beyond the
temple.   
A playboy-type young man helps her and takes her out into the world and ends up falling in love with her at the end and risking his
life which ends up saving the temple because it forces the woman to learn a new
fight move.


Following the description & actress leads to "Baak nin hiu gap" (Love For All Seasons) from 2003 with Sammi Cheng. A recap mentions an all-woman temple where a heart-broken member goes insane, and the 'playboy taking her into the world' bit seems to appear in its trailer.

This is Sammi Cheng Sau-Man in the film Magic Kitchen.
I found this by doing a Google image search. A bit more Googling led me to the HKMDB page for Magic Kitchen which features this image labelled as "Jerry Yan Cheng-Xu, 
Sammi Cheng Sau-Man"


ecw416, is this the right movie? Or did you put up the picture to ID the actress? If it doesn't seem to fit, I'm posting another possibility below that might fit your description and stars this actress.
